# NuoDB Equivalent to SQL Server CTE

Tags: nuodb

What is the NuoDB equivalent to SQL Server's Common Table Expressions (CTE) if any? Maybe a temp table? I'm evaluating whether or not I can replace that functionality or not.

Comment: Another NewSQL alternative  you might want to check out is Clustrix, which does support temporary tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuoDB does support temp tables and I think that would be the closest equivalent to CTE. NuoDB online doc has this; http://doc.nuodb.com/display/doc/CREATE+TABLE